# Verify my lasagne

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, decision-problem

### Scenario

I often cook lasagne, but I also have a few mistakes. Since I repeat these faults so often, I thought I maybe could do a program that checks if I did everything right.

### Valid lasagne

A valid lasagne is

- At least 5 columns wide
- At least 4 layers high

  - Excluding extra cheese
- The top layer is cheese (represented by `,`)
- The second layer is sauce (represented by either `@` or `#`)
- After that the layers alternate (1 layer sauce, 1 layer noodles (represented by either `~` or `-`))
- Each column can have either one or two layers of cheese

### The program

Should

- take a lasagne string as input

  - multiline string
  - string array
  - the string only contains the chars `,@#~-`
  - Rectangular
  - Padded with spaces if necessary
- Output whether it's a valid lasagne

  - Any thing that's thruthy in your language if valid
  - Nothing or anything that's falsy in your language
- be either

  - a full program
  - a function
  - that only uses functionality that was implemented before the 14.12.2016

### Test cases

```
,, ,
,,,,,,
@@@###
~~~~~-
@##@@#

--> truthy


@@@#
----
@@##
----
@###

--> falsy (cause of cheese and width (You don't have to print the stuff in the brackets))


,,,,,
-----
@####
-----
@@@@@

--> falsy (have the sauce as last layer)
```

### Winning criteria

The

- shortest

  - in bytes
  - [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)
- functional

submission wins.

Comment: **Please** close that parenthesis.

Comment: Question: Does it need to be horizontally rectangular? i.e. what if it is 10 rows high and 9 columns wide?

Comment: The spec says it can only `,@#~-` with the exception of spaces as padding, but the first test case contains spaces in the middle of a line.

Comment: @feersum "Padded with spaces if necessary"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>38</s> 34 bytes

*Thanks to Grimy for saving 4 bytes.*

Have a regex with your lasagne.

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
^([, ]+¶)?,{5,}(¶[@#]+¶[-~]*){2,}$
```

Assumes that the input ends with a trailing linefeed. Prints `1` (match) for valid lasagnes and `0` (no match) for invalid ones.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#lVAxDoMwDNzvFZZMpVCcpVKnDM0fGCOq/oPCs/KAfCyNCVkL3OK709mynSIcxo9zuJlSvl1@myA0DSn2L5mfspgUg2c1gl2nez8/ZOlyFiEhgmyA956ZsSosCi@6qTOZXV2ItuEahS2A9uxMm@uszagON64ASEriKHRin79XXn9ILT8)

#### Explanation

This is just a standard .NET regex matched against the input, except that Retina provides the alias `¶` for linefeeds or `\n`.

Since the input is guaranteed to be rectangular, we only need to check the width of the lasagne on one of the rows.

```
^           # Anchor the regex to the beginning of the input.
([, ]+¶)?   # Match an optional first line of only commas an spaces.
,{5,}       # Match at least 5 commas.
(           # Match this at least twice to ensure at least two layers of sauce.
  ¶[@#]+    #   Match a line of sauce.
  ¶[-~]*    #   Match a line of pasta. This line may be empty (which would
            #   indicate the end of the input.
){2,}
$           # Make sure we've indeed reached the end. Note that `$` can
            # match either at the very end of the input, or in front of
            # the trailing linefeed.
```

Comment: If we’re allowed to assume that there’s a final linefeed after the last line (which sounds reasonable), you can use `¶[-~]*` instead of `(¶[-~]+|$)`, saving 4 bytes.

Comment: @Grimy Ah good catch, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

### [Grime](https://github.com/iatorm/grime), 43 bytes

```
e`[ \,]+/?/(\,/[#@]^/[\-~]/+/[#@]/?)+{5-,4-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/grime#HcexDYBACEDRnilIaDRAaLQ@9gCMjVOYuDp6vur/vs7AlGIbtqRYkNdhkfqU8X82Vr53lU27EUUQZAJ3Iged4EuiFw)
Prints `1` for match and `0` for no match.

### Explanation

Grime is designed for matching two-dimensional patterns, which are constructed piece by piece from smaller patterns.
I define the optional top layer first, then the other layers by repeating a vertical stripe.

```
e`                                           Match entire input against pattern:
        /?                                   Optionally
  [ \,]+                                     a row of spaces and commas,
          /                                  below that
           (                       )         this pattern
                                    +        repeated horizontally
                                     {5-,4-  having size at least 5x4. 
                                             The brace is closed implicitly.
                                             "This pattern" is a vertical stripe containing
            \,                               a comma,
              /                              below that
               [#@]^/[\-~]                   a sauce character on top of a noodle character
                                             (the ^/ is like / but with higher precedence)
                          /+                 repeated vertically,
                            /                below that
                                 /?          optionally
                             [#@]            a sauce character.
```